# Entity framework 4.0 quering with linq using Substring

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a problem getting result from a database by specific column value using LINQ.

This is my table Customer(Id, Name, Surname, ExternalID). ExternalID is a varchar column with specific string pattern, for instance 01_johnDoe.

Let's say that I want to get customer johnDoe and my mehod gets string johnDoe.

I'm able to do that by this way :

```
public<Customer> GetMeACustomer(string customerExternalID)
{
using(var context=new MyContext())
{

var customerObject=(from c in contex.Customer where c.ExternalID.Contains(customerExternalID)).Single()   

}

}
```

This code is not good enough simply because query sent to Database is using operator LIKE. This is slow (I have huge number of customer). 
I couldn't implement inside linq something like this :

```
   var example = ExternalIDFromDatabase.Substring(ExternalIDFromDatabase.IndexOf("_") + 1, customerExternalID.Count());
```

by this code I could simply say

```
var customerObject=(from c in contex.Customer where c.ExternalID.Substring(c.ExternalID.IndexOf("_") + 1, customerExternalID.Count())==customerExternalID).Single()
```

But it's not working. 
Any Ideas ?
Than you

Comment: check this [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work when you replace `customerExternalID.Count()` with `customerExternalID.Length` or when you create local variable (let say `customerExternalIDCount`) and assign count to it. Probably provider tries to translate this `Count` call into SQL.

BTW you probably want to use `Substring` method without specifing `length`. If there was for example `01_johnRobin` and `02_johnRobins` in database, you would get 2 results for `johnRobin` `customerExternalID`.